# Importação e leitura de arquivo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC com Entity Framework 4 e SQL Server, onde existe uma `Action` que recebe via `POST` um arquivo `csv`.

Levando em consideração o uso de memória, tempo e recursos de processamento ou qualquer questão quanto ao banco de dados, qual dessas duas opções de código é a mais recomendada?

> Um número aproximado de 15000 linhas poderá ser usado no arquivo.

**Opção 1:**

```
var postedFile = Request.Files[0];

using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            // Validações

            db.Produtos.Add(new Produto { Descricao = values[0], Valor = values[1] });
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

**Opção 2:**

```
var postedFile = Request.Files[0];

using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
    var produtos = new List<Produto>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');

        // Validações

        var produto = new Produto
        {
            Descricao = values[0],
            Valor = values[1]
        };

        produtos.Add(produto);
    }

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        produtos.ForEach(p => db.Produto.Add(p));

            db.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

> Existe uma **Opção 3** melhor?

Comment: Você está salvando um arquivo `.csv` na sua base de dados num array de bytes?

Comment: não não, quero fazer tudo na memória...

Comment: Bom eu acho que quase entendi, você está lendo o arquivo e adicionado cada linha na sua base de dados? Modelo do arquivo .csv? ajudaria bastante!

Comment: @João é isso mesmo, e o modelo é `Descrição;Valor` pelos dados da pergunta. :P

Comment: @João na verdade minha dúvida não é como fazer, mas sim qual a melhor maneira de fazer. O trecho acima é só um exemplo, neste caso teríamos duas colunas, uma descrição e um valor separados por ponto e vírgula. A ideia é fazer a leitura do arquivo sem salva-lo no disco, mas para isso surgem algumas dúvidas: qual solução requer menos uso de memória? Ao criar uma TransactionScope com 15000 itens posso prejudicar o desempenho da aplicação ou do banco?

Comment: Então, @JedaiasRodrigues você não postou isso na sua pergunta, esse cenário de 15.000 mil linhas até para SQLClient puro é complicado. eu entendi a leitura em memória, mas, faltam pré requisitos que você acabou de falar por exemplo 15.000 mil linhas é um fator preocupante para `Entity Framework`. Vendo assim A primeira é a melhor com um ajuste de `try catch roolback`

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues qual a versão do ASP MVC?

Comment: @João entendi, estarei editando a pergunta. Estou usando MVC 4, o projeto é antigo.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues, te aconselho a não fazer uso do `List<T>.ForEach`, ele torna o codigo ruim de debuggar, é mais lento, e está atribuindo uma função a lista que não é dela. Quando a ler o CSV, tome cuidado com caracteres de escape e outras regrinhas do mesmo, então te aconselho a usar o [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). Por fim, por questões de perfomance, evite salvar os 15.000 registros de uma vez, faça um SaveChanges a cada 100~1000 registros, ou melhor faça uso do [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Como eu disse para você, e o @TobyMosque disse acima, podes utilizar o SqlBulk. Necessitava salvar na faixa de 100 mil registros em meu BD. Utilizando o foreach demorava uns 5 minutos. Ao invés de salvar direto, eu utilizei o foreach para salvar os dados em uma lista, e utilizei o BulkInsert, para inserir os dados. A tarefa mudou de 5 minutos para cerca de 15 segundos. Caso precise, avise que elaboro uma resposta mais tarde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe uma Opção 3 melhor?

Existe. [Comece instalando o FileHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/) e o [BulkInsert para o Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/).

Use algo parecido com a opção 2:

```
using FileHelpers;
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;

var postedFile = Request.Files[0];

using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Produto>();
    var produtos = engine.ReadStream(reader);

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        db.BulkInsert(produtos);
        db.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de decorar `Produto` com:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class Produto { ... }
```

---

#### Sobre a Opção 1

Adicionando um produto de cada vez ao contexto fará com que este contexto fique lento com alguns milhares de registros. A operação pode ficar excessivamente lenta e levar muito mais tempo que o desejado.

#### Sobre a Opção 2

Não é muito diferente da opção 1, com um agravante: você está usando mais memória para manter a lista e depois para adicioná-la ao contexto (não é muito mais memória, mas é).

> Durante a transação, existe o risco de que a tabela fique bloqueada pra possíveis consultas por outros usuários?

Existe sim, considerando que o nível de isolamento padrão do escopo transacional é o mais alto possível (`Serializable`).

É possível mudar o nível de isolamento dos registros ([veja a opção `TransactionOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)).

> O BulkInsert insere os itens em blocos?

Sim, como um bloco só. Não há separação em blocos menores.

> Posso fazer o controle disso?

Pode, montando os blocos em memória antes.

> A *Transaction* fica aberta durante a inserção dos 15000 itens?

Fica aberta até que o `using` termine ou que `scope.Complete()` seja chamado.

> Isso não pode interferir na performance?

Transações são mais lentas que operações normais de inserção porque o banco de dados executa uma série de operações para validar este escopo. O ganho de performance vem através do *Bulk Insert*.

> Outra questão é que meu projeto é antigo, e está usando a versão 4 do EF, mas o BulkInsert tem o EF 4.1 em suas dependências, e tenho medo que ao instala-lo seja feita a atualização do EF e cause alguma dor de cabeça.

Desconheço problemas com a atualização da versão do EF, a não ser que você faça uso do `OriginalValues` de alguma entidade em algum lugar. Fora isto, eu aconselho sim a atualização.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta! Será que você poderia explanar mais um pouco sobre o porque de usar o FileHelpers e o BulkInsert, e qual o problema nas opções apresentadas?

Comment: Durante a transação, existe o risco de que a tabela fique bloqueada pra possíveis consultas por outros usuários? O BulkInsert insere os itens em blocos? Posso fazer o controle disso? A Transaction fica aberta durante a inserção dos 15000 itens? Isso não pode interferir na performance?

Comment: Outra questão é que meu projeto é antigo, e está usando a versão 4 do EF, mas o BulkInsert tem o EF 4.1 em suas dependências, e tenho medo que ao instala-lo seja feita a atualização do EF e cause alguma dor de cabeça.

Comment: [;(](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131879/erro-ao-usar-entity-framework-bulkinsert/131894#131894)

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira também seria utilizar BulkInsert feito a mão, um método genérico que lê as propriedades e monta um insert super rápido...

Tem um repositório github que contém dois métodos muito úteis para operações Bulk: BulkInsert and BulkUpdate utilizando MySql e EF6+.

Basicamente, ambas funções encontradas no link leem as propriedades genérica passada nos métodos e monta as querys referentes (update ou insert)...

Obs1: O projeto foi desenvolvido visando as necessidades particulares, caso por exemplo o banco seja diferente, será necessário adaptações, mas já é um começo.

Obs²: O projeto está aberto para aqueles que desejam aprimorá-lo no intuito de gerar valor para a comunidade.

Por favor, de uma olhada em [aqui](https://github.com/brunocanmaster/BulkInsert-And-BulkUpdate-MySql-EF6-)