# Erro ao usar Entity Framework BulkInsert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC em .Net Framework 4.0 com Entity Framework 5.0, onde adicionei o [BulkInsert-ef5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef5/), mas no seguinte trecho ocorre erro:

```
using (MeuEntities context = new MeuEntities())
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; //  Com ou sem essa linha o resultado é o mesmo erro.
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.BulkInsert(produtos); // Daqui vai direto pra Exception
    }
}
```

Minha classe `Produto` foi criada automaticamente pelo EF:

```
namespace meuProjeto.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Produto
    {
        public int ProdutoId { get; set; } // Auto incremento no Banco de Dados (SQL Server)
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoriaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Para preencher minha lista de produtos, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
ProdutoImport[] produtosImport = null;
var postedFile = Request.Files[0];
using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ProdutoImport>();
    produtosImport = engine.ReadStream(reader);
}

var produtos = produtosImport.Select(p => new Produto
{
    Descricao = p.Descricao,
    Categoria = p.CategoriaId
})).ToList();
```

Minha classe `ProdutoImport`:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class ProdutoImport
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
}
```

Todas as linhas do meu arquivo possuem as duas colunas: `Descrição;CategoriaId`.

O erro gerado é:

> O espaço 'CSSpace' não tem uma coleção associada.

**InnerException**: Null

**StackTrace:**

```
   em System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required)
   em System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace)
   em EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.get_TphData() na c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:linha 59
   em EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.MapEntity(String typeFullName, EdmType edmItem) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:linha 284
   em EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappings.DbMapping..ctor(DbContext context) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappings\DbMapping.cs:linha 80
   em EntityFramework.MappingAPI.EfMap.Get(DbContext context) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\EfMap.cs:linha 60
   em EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Extensions.MappingApiExtensions.Db(DbContext ctx, Type type) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Extensions\MappingApiExtensions.cs:linha 51
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 keySelector, Func'2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer'1 comparer)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 keySelector, Func'2 elementSelector)
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Helpers.MappedDataReader'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 enumerable, IEfBulkInsertProvider provider) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Helpers\MappedDataReader.cs:linha 58
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.Run[T](IEnumerable'1 entities, SqlTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.cs:linha 22
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase'2.Run[T](IEnumerable'1 entities, IDbTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:linha 77
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase'2.Run[T](IEnumerable'1 entities, BulkInsertOptions options) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:linha 105
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable'1 entities, SqlBulkCopyOptions sqlBulkCopyOptions, Nullable'1 batchSize) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:linha 95
   em EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext context, IEnumerable'1 entities, Nullable'1 batchSize) na c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:linha 75
   em meuProjeto.Areas.Administrador.Controllers.MeuController.MinhaAction(Int32 param1, Int32 param2) na c:\...\meuProjeto\Areas\Administrador\Controllers\MeuController.cs:linha 8567
```

**TargetSite**

```
{System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ItemCollection GetItemCollection(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace, Boolean)}
```

Comment: O que você faz com sua Lista var produtos = produtosImport ?

Comment: No primeiro bloco de código da pergunta, uso a variável produtos para o BulkInsert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acontece que o BulkInsert só funciona com DatabaseFirst se você estiver usando o EntityFramework 6.

Você pode confirmar isso na [página do Codeplex do pacote](http://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=codeplex).

No StackOverflow, tem [uma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404942/4190610) [de dois anos atrás] parecida com a sua, onde o desenvolvedor do pacote diz que ele foi feito a princípio pra ser usado com CodeFirst.